# Init dynamic object to be used as a certain instance of type

Tags: c#, dynamic

Reproduction:

Snippet 1:

```
class A{
   A(int i){}
   A(string s){}
   A(Form b){}
   A(Stream b){}
   //...more constructors but no one accepts object type
}
```

Snippet 2:

```
A assign(object obj)
{
    dynamic d=obj;
    //do something with d or obj?
    A a=new A(d);
    return a;
}
```

How to make the line `A a=new A(d);` working?

Edit:

How to make the line `A a=new A(d);` working without dynamic type mechanism?

Comment: If you *really* have a class which takes an `int`, a `string`, a `Form`, or a `Stream` in its constructor, chances are you're doing it wrong. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: You haven't said what's wrong with the current code as you've shown it. I'd expect it to work... what actually happens, and what would you expect to happen?

Comment: Also, this appears to work just fine: http://rextester.com/UGB86702

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add A(object obj){}

To A's constructor, then use GetType() to identify it.

```
        public A(object obj)
        {
            if(obj is int)
                //Do something with the int.
            if(obj is string)
                //Do something with the string.
            if(obj is Form)
                //Do something with the Form.

            //etc...        
        }
```